# Password Validation fails using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern, insomnia

I am getting an error ValidationError: Path password is required, when trying to register a new User. I am new to Node, programming, and authentication.

Here is the User model and schema code I have, I attempted to comment it thoroughly.

**User router**

> router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
> try {
> let {email, password, passwordCheck, displayName} = req.body;
>
> ```
>     // validate email, password and passwordCheck
>     if (!email || !password || !passwordCheck)
>         return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Not all fields have been entered." });
>     if (password.length < 5)
>         return res.status(400).json({ msg: "The password needs to be at least 5 characters long." });
>     if (password !== passwordCheck)
>         return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Passwords do not match. Enter the same password twice for verification." });
>
>
>    //verify if the new user already exists in the MongoDB
>     const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
>     if (existingUser)
>         return res.status(400).json({ msg: "An account with this email already exists." });
>
>     if (!displayName) displayName = email; //if no display name, email is display name
>
>     const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); //creates random string used for hashing password
>     const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
>         if (err) {
>             console.log('Issue with hashing bcrypt');
>         }// else {console.log('Successful Hash: ' + hash);} add if error checking
>     });
>     //save new user to DB with hashed password
>     const newUser = new User({
>         email,
>         "password":passwordHash,
>         displayName,
>     });
>     console.log(newUser);
>     const savedUser = await newUser.save(); //save the new user to database
>     res.json(savedUser); //respond to front end with saved user
>
> } catch (err) {
>     console.log('Error registering user');
>     res.status(500).json({ err });} });
> ```

**User Model**

> ```
> const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
> email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
> password: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 5},
> displayName: {type: String} });
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `password: passwordHash` instead of `"password": passwordHash`.
If it doesn't help then you should console.log your passwordHash to check whether it has a value or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did console.log my passwordHash and noticed that it was undefined; realized I didn't need a function for the callback.